# Flutter oneSignal notifications icon not set

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notifications, onesignal

I'm using one signal within my flutter app and everything is fine except the notifications have no icon ( comes with a default bill icon ).

I have read the documentation for **one signal** and generated an **AssetsImage** by **Android Studio** in `PROJECT/android/res/` with name `ic_stat_onesignal_default`

Then I built the app using the command `flutter run --release` on a real device and still, the notification comes with default bill icon instead of my app icon!!

Is there some code required in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use these tool and upload image that is trnasperts
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default

for onesignal the folders names is drawable-xxxx
so you just download from the tool and extract inside the android\app\src\main\res

**Note :-**
Starting with Android 5, the OS forces Small Notification Icons to **be all white when your app targets Android API 21+**. If you don't make a correct icon, it will most likely be displayed as a bell or solid white icon in the status bar.

Comment: Make sure to uninstall and re-install the app again to apply changes!

Answer (score 1):

> just do some simple things and it changes your default notification icon. I also face this problem in 2021 but I resolve it

> in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_stat_onesignal_default" />
```

> in build.gradle

```
 buildTypes {
  
  debug {
       defaultConfig {
     manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "your onesignal app id put here",
                             onesignal_google_project_number: "your project number put here"]
   }
}
```

}

> put your pic in app/main/res/drawable and also in all mipmap with the name "ic_stat_onesignal_default" ..please must use this name otherwise it's not working ..

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the following line in AndroidManifest.xml. Also Create folders starting with drawable-xxx.. You can use online tools for that...

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="com.onesignal.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_onesignal_default" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationAccentColor.DEFAULT"
    android:value="FFFFFF" />
```

Don't Forget to generate app icons in PROJECT/android/res/.
Name of the file: - ic_stat_onesignal_default
Name of Folders :-

```
drawable-xhdpi | drawable-xxhdpi | drawable-xxxhdpi | drawable-hdpi  | drawable-mdpi
```