# Implementing small icon in Application

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, onesignal, android-13

followed whole Documentations by one signal and created asset by using Notification icon generator by this link:

[text](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default)

I've put  assets files in drawable but When notification is received the bell icon is showing instead of app icon or custom icon in my flutter app  .

bell icon is showing in android 13,its working fine in android 11 or below the versions in flutter app

Comment: check this if it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205374/flutter-onesignal-notifications-icon-not-set